# Java Multithreading with timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I need to create a multithreaded Java application for recursive directory search wherein I need to search for all files/folders based on the search-string. 
Example : :

- Search-string - 'hello'
- Search-directory : 'C:\'
- Expectation here is that I need to recursively search all files & folders in C:\ having
  name as hello

My idea is to spawn a thread per directory to have a better performance.

Challenge is that we have a timeout factor wherein all the matching files/folders are to be shown within the timeout interval - if timeout happens before complete search is done, we need to show whatever results are available. I am pretty confused on how to handle this timeout - can you please help?

Cheers,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Think you can spawn a child thread for search - say 'ThreadA' from main thread. Have a waited-join for Main Thread and ThreadA. Let this child thread 'ThreadA' spawn other threads and have a join for the same. Let all the child threads use ConcurrentLinkedQueue to capture the results - so, after the Main Thread returns after the join timeout, it can print the values in the Queue